# What modules can I use to ping a website in Django from the database?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have model that takes a URL and prints the URL in the front end. How would I ping that website using Django? Is there any package/module that I can use? I've seen django-ping but it hasn't been updated in 7 years.

This is the model

```
class Table(models.Model):
    domain = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Once the ping returns. How would I be able to display the status on the template?

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Why do you need a module? Why not call the os ping command?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm 6 months into django. Can you help me understand those commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can try this one, but you know there is a command for that
https://www.ictshore.com/python/python-ping-tutorial/

```
import subprocess

out = subprocess.run(['ping', 'google.com'], capture_output=True)
print(out.stdout.decode())
```

Comment: Will definitely try this! Thanks @Asinox